# is there any difference in the following sort queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Field1 INT, FieldSomethingElse VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (1, 'b')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (2, null)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (765, 'a')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (NULL, 'd')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (NULL, 'f')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (76, null)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (3, 'r')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field1, FieldSomethingElse) VALUES (40, 'b')

declare @flag bit = 0;

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY
  case when @flag = 1 then  ISNULL(Field1,0) else 0 end  desc , ID  desc

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY
  case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) end desc, ID desc
```

Is there any difference if I write

```
 1. case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) else 0 end desc, ID desc
```

or

```
 2. case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) end desc, ID desc
```

I was advised to use option 1, but for me both options are same because I see the same result. Is there any difference?

how does 1 and 2 options affect the sorting?

Comment: Check the execution plan of each and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first clause:

```
1. case when @flag = 1 then  ISNULL(Field1,0) else 0 end  desc , ID  desc
```

When @flag is not equal to 1 then you'll get 0 returned. 
For the second:

```
2. case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) end desc, ID desc
```

When @flag is not equal to 1 then `null` will be returned.

Since it's in your `order by`, no there won't be any difference in functionality.

Comment: how does this affect the sorting?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the answer to address the impact on your order by. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

i guess there is a little difference. When flag = 0 the following expressions are same

`order by case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) end desc, ID desc`

and

`order by case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) else null end desc, ID desc`

let's assume that instead of **Field1** and **Id** we sort **two bit columns**. In this case, when sorting two columns NULL will be considered.

https://rextester.com/SBDJQ20053

that's why it's recommended to use

```
case when @flag = 1 then ISNULL(Field1,0) else 0 end desc, ID desc
```

to avoid null in sorting